# AWS Sagemaker Incremental Training: should all classes be included in training set?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am looking for a SageMaker object detection algorithm (MXNet) and more particularly in  into incremental training.
I have a base model that will detect bounding boxes for 10 classes in pictures.
when I perform the incremental training, should the training pictures have the 10 classes identified in each one of them?
My problem is that I have training pictures for each individual class but not a set of pictures with all classes identified. For example, in my Training images for class A, all other classes **are not** identified. I have another set of training pictures with just class B identified but nothing else is identified and so on.
Is that an issue to use sagemaker?

Comment: Not necessarily the goal is to provide sufficient examples for each object class they need not necessarily coexist in a single image.